# Integral of $\int\frac1{x}\sqrt[3]{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}dx$

Tags: integration

I could substitute $t=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$ and get $\int\frac{6t^3}{t^6-1}dt$, which leads to partial fractions decomposition with 6 variables. That's annoying and may lead to mistakes. Is there any other way to compute this integral?

Comment: I am not sure whether this helps, what if you try $u = t^3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change $t^2=s$ gives
$$
3\int\frac{s}{s^3-1}\,ds,
$$
which is simpler.